# Authentication fails during login testing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to test custom login (with pytest) but authentication fails returning None.
Here is views.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from my_auth.api.serializers import UserLoginSerializer

class LoginAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer


class UserLoginSerializer(AuthTokenSerializer):
    username = None
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        label=_("Email"),
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'),
                                email=email, password=password)  # returns None

            if not user:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')  # raises
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "email" and "password".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

tests.py

```
import pytest

from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture
def test_user():
    user = MyUser.objects.create(
        email='test@m.com',
        first_name='Firstname',
        last_name='Lastname'
    )
    user.set_password('pass5678')
    return user


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_login(test_user):
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.post(
        path=reverse('login'),
        data={
            'email': 'test@m.com',
            'password': 'pass5678',
        },
        format='json',
    )
    assert(response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK)
    token = Token.objects.get(user=test_user)
    assert(token.key == response.data['token'])
```

Terminal output:

```
========================================================================================================== test session starts ==========================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
django: settings: news_project.settings (from ini)
rootdir: /home/andrei/NEWS/news_project, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: lambda-1.2.4, Faker-8.4.0, common-subject-1.0.5, assert-utils-0.2.2, drf-1.1.2, fixture-order-0.1.3, django-4.3.0
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

my_auth/tests.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                                [ 50%]
news/tests.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

=============================================================================================================== FAILURES ================================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_login _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

test_user = <MyUser: test@m.com>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_login(test_user):
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.post(
            path=reverse('login'),
            data={
                'email': 'test@m.com',
                'password': 'pass5678',
            },
            format='json',
        )
>       assert(response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK)
E       assert 400 == 200
E        +  where 400 = <Response status_code=400, "application/json">.status_code
E        +  and   200 = status.HTTP_200_OK

my_auth/tests.py:78: AssertionError
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING  django.request:log.py:224 Bad Request: /api/auth/login/
======================================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================================
FAILED my_auth/tests.py::test_login - assert 400 == 200
====================================================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 3.63s ======================================================================================================
```

This is output when I do `print(response.data)` in test_login

```
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Unable to log in with provided credentials.', code='authorization')]}
```

At first I thought that rest_framework.request.Request object is not passed to the UserLoginSerializer's validate(), but it is actually. Moreover, it's almost the same as the Request obtained when I send POST request via Postman. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with how you are setting the password. What happens if you yet the password in your create statement instead of separately? user = MyUser.objects.create(password='pass5678',
        email='test@m.com',
        first_name='Firstname',
        last_name='Lastname'
    )

Comment: @sur.la.route .create() method doesn't hash the provided password, thus it can't be used for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to call `save` the user after calling `set_password`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_user():
    user = MyUser.objects.create(
        email='test@m.com',
        first_name='Firstname',
        last_name='Lastname'
    )
    user.set_password('pass5678')
    user.save()
    return user
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

> Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.